# Hint to scrape a page using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am veeeeeryyyyy nooob...

I'm trying to scrape this page https://dungeonsanddragons.fandom.com/it/wiki/Allarme

and i would like to extract the text after the string **Gittata:**
(in this case, i'd like to have **9 metri**)
Any hint?
thanks a lot
LV

Unfortunately I don't recognize any tag I can use, I'd like to "print text from the N line"

This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://dungeonsanddragons.fandom.com/it/wiki/Aiuto"
data = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')


#GITTATA

gittata = soup.find_all('p')[1]
```

...that's all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/). We will not write code to specification for you here. Plagiarism is a serious academic offense; aside from that, we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and analyze the task, identify the logical steps to solve the problem, and figure out *where you are actually stuck*. Make sure to check if the issue is already addressed in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find `<b>` tag with text `Gittata` and then get next sibling string:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://dungeonsanddragons.fandom.com/it/wiki/Aiuto"
data = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")


g = soup.select_one("b:-soup-contains(Gittata)").find_next_sibling(string=True).strip()
print(g)
```

Prints:

```
9 metri
```